# Visual Studio 2019, Shift-Alt-F10 stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In VS2017 or prior this is a shortcut for quick-action, for example I can quickly add a new reference to a namespace in using.

But it does not work any more in VS2019. Any work-around/

Answer (score 1):

The default keyboard shortcut for quick-action for Visual Studio is `Ctrl + .`  [Quick Action Shorcut VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019)

Perhaps you changed it in 2017 to Ctrl-Alt-F10? By default, Ctrl-Alt-F10 is only a shortcut in 2017 for debugging: [Shortcuts in 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)

Hope this helps